# Print byte string so java application can see it or receive byte info and parse it properly

Tags: php

I have to print the content of an image in bytes. I send a response in the MIME Multipart/Related Content-type.
So the body of my response is like this:

```
$eol="\r\n";
echo "Content-Type: image/jpeg".$eol;
echo "Content-Length: ".strlen($image).$eol;
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary".$eol;
---Content of image in bytes----
```

So this is how I tried to print the bytes.

```
//I receive an array of bytes from image
$imageContent=file_get_contents('./1.jpg');
$byte_array = unpack('C*', $imageContent);

foreach ($byte_array as $byte) 
{
    echo $byte;
}
```

or

```
$image="";
foreach ($byte_array as $byte) 
{
    $image.=$byte;
}
echo $image;
```

Both shows me an empty result after trying to print the bytes. So how can I do it?

**UPDATE**:
var_dump of $byte_array is like:

```
    array(129743) {
      [1]=>
      int(255)
      [2]=>
      int(216)
      [3]=>
      int(255)
      [4]=>
      int(224)
      [5]=>
      int(0)
      [6]=>
      int(16)
      [7]=>
      int(74)
      [8]=>
      int(70)
      [9]=>
      int(73)
      [10]=>
      int(70)
      [11]=>
      int(0)
      [12]=>
      int(1)
      [13]=>
      int(1)
      [14]=>
      int(0)
      [15]=>
      int(0)
      [16]=>
      int(1)
      [17]=>
      int(0)
      [18]=>
      int(1)
      [19]=>
      int(0)
      [20]=>
      int(0)
      [21]=>
      int(255)
      [22]=>
      int(219)
      [23]=>
      int(0)
      [24]=>
      int(67)
      [25]=>
      int(0)
      [26]=>
      int(2)
      [27]=>
      int(1)
      [28]=>
      int(1)
      [29]=>
      int(1)
      [30]=>
      int(1)
      [31]=>
      int(1)
      [32]=>
      int(2)
      [33]=>
      int(1)
      [34]=>
      int(1)
      [35]=>
      int(1)
      [36]=>
      int(2)
      [37]=>
      int(2)
      [38]=>
      int(2)
      [39]=>
      int(2)
...}
```

**UPDATE**
changed `unpack('C*', $imageContent);` to `pack('a*', $vectorContent);`
and pass this data. Java coder says that it's binary data. I'm waiting whet he test that the image is right.
I receive data from him in format like:

```
436f 6e74 656e 742d 4c65 6e67 7468 3a20
3138 3830 0d0a 0d0a ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46
4946 0001 0101 0060 0060 0000 ffdb 0043
0010 0b0c 0e0c 0a10 0e0d 0e12 1110 1318
281a 1816 1618 3123 251d 283a 333d 3c39
3338 3740 485c 4e40 4457 4537 3850 6d51
```

When I try this:

```
$query = file_get_contents("php://input");
$queryHex=unpack("H*", $query);
```

vardump of `$queryHex` gives me:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  string(2558) "3433366620366537342036353665203734326420346336352036653637203734363820336132300a3331333820333833..."
```

How to receive proper data?

Comment: Can you debug the script to see if the loop is executed multiple times? If so, then you should have some output. Inspect what the ``unpack`` function returns.

Comment: I've added the var_dump of unpack. SO I'm sure that it's  fine. How can I pirnt it in propper way?